# wcf callback exception after updating to .net 4.0

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, exception

I have a wcf service that uses callbacks with DualHttpBindings. The service pushes back a datatable of search results the client (for a long running search) as it finds them.

This worked fine in .Net 3.5. Since I updated to .Net 4.0, it bombs out with a System.Runtime.FatalException that actually kills the IIS worker process.  I have no idea how to even go about starting to fix this.  Any recommendations appreciated.

The info from the resulting event logs is pasted below:

---

> An unhandled exception occurred and
>   the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/CP
>
> Process ID: 5284
>
> **> Exception:
>   System.Runtime.FatalException**
>
> **> Message: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.**
>
> **StackTrace**:    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext
>   request, Boolean cleanThread,
>   OperationContext
>   currentOperationContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext
>   request, OperationContext
>   currentOperationContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item
>   item)    at
>   System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Dispatch()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.ProcessDuplexMessage(WsrmMessageInfo
>   info)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.HandleReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnReceiveCompletedStatic(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.InputAsyncResult`1.OnInputComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item
>   item)    at
>   System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Dispatch()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes,
>   NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32
>   error, UInt32 bytesRead,
>   NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes,
>   NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
>
> **> InnerException:**
>   **> System.NullReferenceException**
>
> **Message**: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.
>
> **StackTrace**:    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ThreadContext.Enter(Boolean
>   setImpersonationContext)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean
>   setImpersonationContext)    at
>   System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   **System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK - I found the answer.  Very Strange, but simply put the following attribute on the WCF callback wrapper class:

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
```

Thanks to Cauldwell.net for the answer: http://www.cauldwell.net/patrick/blog/CategoryView,category,CodeGen.aspx

From cauldwell.net:

> The problem, it turned out, was that
>   ASP.NET uses (by default) a little
>   thing called the
>   SynchronizationContext.  As near as I
>   can tell (I haven't researched this
>   thoroughly, to be honest) one of it's
>   jobs it to make sure that any
>   callbacks get run on the UI thread,
>   thereby obviating the need to call
>   Control.Invoke like you do in
>   WinForms.  In my case, that additional
>   lock was giving something fits, and it
>   was trying to clean stuff up on a
>   thread that wasn't around any more,
>   hence to NullReferenceException.

Comment: That did the trick! Although my scenario was a bit different from the article in the sense that the exception was thrown before that callback method was invoked.